own solana blockhain server to send requests
I would like to create my own “server” to handle requests such as: Track transactions without rate limits. I think this also relieves the load on the Solana network and contributes to the health of the network. the server is based on Ubuntu.
I found the following guide and would like to ask you whether it is correct so far. the server has 3 SSDs. one for the os 256gb, one for accounts 1tb and one for the ledger 2tb. Please be considerate, I'm still pretty new at this.

Install Dependencies

Update your system and install the necessary dependencies:
bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install -y git curl build-essential pkg-config libssl-dev

Install Rust

Solana requires Rust, so install it using the following command:
bash
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
source $HOME/.cargo/env

Install Solana

Download and install the Solana software:
bash
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.13.3/install)"
Add Solana to your path:
bash
export PATH="/home/$(whoami)/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"

Configure the Validator

Create a directory for the ledger and configure your validator:
bash
mkdir -p ~/solana-validator
solana-keygen new --outfile ~/solana-validator/validator-keypair.json

Download the Genesis Block

Download the genesis block and configure your node:
bash
solana-validator 
--identity ~/solana-validator/validator-keypair.json 
--ledger ~/solana-validator/ledger 
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d 
--limit-ledger-size 
--no-port-check 
--no-snapshot-fetch 
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 
--enable-rpc-transaction-history 
--full-rpc-api

Run the Validator

Start your validator with the following command:
bash
solana-validator 
--identity ~/solana-validator/validator-keypair.json 
--vote-account ~/solana-validator/vote-account-keypair.json 
--ledger ~/solana-validator/ledger 
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d 
--rpc-port 8899 
--enable-rpc-transaction-history 
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 
--limit-ledger-size 
--log ~/solana-validator/solana-validator.log

umm. you might need to stop what you're doing. it simply does not work that way. if you want to become a "Validator" you need to pass all requirements especially with the hardware - and ask everyone to stake on your validator.
if you simply want to run SVM (ie. your own network, outside of the mainnet) that will be a different topic.
if you simply want to run locally on your machine, just run solana-test-validator

haha thanks for the reply but ive the hardware. i just want to have the mainnet blochchain data to do a few request without rate limits ..  u understand?
